# What happens if PD tries to consume more than allowed PSE power provided?

Tags: poe

What happens if a Powered Device (PD) tries to consume more than allowed (Power Sourcing Equipment) PSE power provided, even though it has requested a set amount of power?

http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrta2/tidrta2.pdf

Example: Let's say the load on the output wanted 40V @ 1.3A but the output was rated for 40V @ 1.15A

Comment: Please replace "PD" and "PSE" with whatever they stand for.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what device you're talking about, so we don't have to run it down from a schematic.

Comment: (YBOAISE) Your book on acronyms is somewhat extreme.

Answer (score 1):

If the Powered Device (PD) draws more power than its class, then the current limit would be hit on the (or other PSE controller) TPS2372 and it would revert to an idle state:

[image]
Source: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2372.pdf

This should never happen however, as part of the spec the PD needs to make sure that it never draws more power than it's class.